# Caffe's configuration for Cohn-Kanade dataset

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, convolution, caffe, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to make a facial expression recognizer using Caffe and the [Cohn-Kanade database](http://www.pitt.edu/~emotion/ck-spread.htm).

This is my train prototxt configuration:

```
def configureTrainProtoTxt(lmdb, batch_size):

n = caffe.NetSpec()
n.data, n.label = L.Data(batch_size=batch_size, backend=P.Data.LMDB, source=lmdb,
                         transform_param=dict(scale= 1 / 126.0), ntop=2)

n.conv1 = L.Convolution(n.data, kernel_size=2, pad=1, param=dict(lr_mult=1), num_output=10, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
n.conv1 = L.Convolution(n.data, kernel_size=2, pad=1, param=dict(lr_mult=1), num_output=10, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
n.conv1 = L.Convolution(n.data, kernel_size=5, pad=0, num_output=20, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
n.pool1 = L.Pooling(n.conv1, kernel_size=5, stride=2, pool=P.Pooling.MAX)
n.conv2 = L.Convolution(n.pool1, kernel_size=3, num_output=10, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier')) 
n.pool2 = L.Pooling(n.conv2, kernel_size=2, stride=2, pool=P.Pooling.MAX)
n.ip1 = L.InnerProduct(n.pool2, num_output=100, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
n.relu1 = L.ReLU(n.ip1, in_place=True)
n.ip2 = L.InnerProduct(n.relu1, num_output=2, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
n.loss = L.SoftmaxWithLoss(n.ip2, n.label)

return n.to_proto()
```

This is my trainning function, that I got it from lenet example:

```
def train(solver):

niter = 200
test_interval = 10 

train_loss = zeros(niter)
test_acc = zeros(int(np.ceil(niter / test_interval)))
output = zeros((niter, 32, 2))

for it in range(niter):
    solver.step(1)  

    train_loss[it] = solver.net.blobs['loss'].data

    solver.test_nets[0].forward(start='conv1')
    output[it] = solver.test_nets[0].blobs['ip2'].data[:32]

    if it % test_interval == 0:
        print 'Iteration', it, 'testing...'

        correct = 0

        for test_it in range(100):
            solver.test_nets[0].forward()
            correct += sum(solver.test_nets[0].blobs['ip2'].data.argmax(1) == solver.test_nets[0].blobs['label'].data)

        test_acc[it // test_interval] = correct / 1e4


_, ax1 = subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(arange(niter), train_loss)
ax2.plot(test_interval * arange(len(test_acc)), test_acc, 'r')
ax1.set_xlabel('iteration')
ax1.set_ylabel('train loss')
ax2.set_ylabel('test accuracy')
show()
```

I'm only using the Neutral and Surprise faces (if I solve my problem I'll use more emotions). But my net has only 28% of accuracy. I'd like to know the low accuracy has to with a problem in the network configuration, with the logic inside my train function or if my training db is too small?. This is my dataset discription:

Train dataset: 56 images of Neutral faces. 60 images of Surprise faces.
Test dataset: 15 images of Neutral faces. 15 images of Surprise faces.

All images are 32x32 and in grayscale.
And my batch_size is 32.

Please, can someone help me to known what is my problem?

Comment: Please, specify what is the size of your training and test sets. The link you've provided contains MS Access files, which several people (including me) find difficult to open.

Comment: Moreover, you didn't specify the batch size.

Comment: Thank you Flavio Ferrara, I edited my question.

Comment: Have you tried to change your batch size?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But like I said on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761643/caffe-accuracy-bigger-than-100) I get a bigger accuracy than 100 percent. I think that my problem is with my train function. But I dont know where.